# How to Find a word with spaces in livecode

Tags: livecode

How to find a word with space (eg: i want to find a word "X1 X2 X3"). I am using the following code

```
put the text of field "f4" into xx
    find xx in field "f1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LiveCode, the space character delimits words -- a single word doesn't contain spaces. If there's only one instance of the string of characters you're searching for, you could use the offset function:

```
put "X1 X2 X3" into theString
put the text of fld "f4" into temp
put offset(theString,temp) into theNum
```

The variable theNum will contain the number of characters before the first character of the string, or will contain 0 if the string is not found in the field's text.

Comment: I want to find the word in the scrolling field "f1" and input string given through the filed f4. then how i apply this code

Comment: Change the first line of the example -- put the text of field "f4" into theString, and put the text of fld "f1" into the temp variable -- put the text of fld "f1" into temp.  You could trigger the search action using the returnInField message sent to a field when pressing the return key, or by using a separate "Search" button near field "f4".